# How to make a keyboard Shortcut <Command + S> to save from multiple windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, nswindow, save

OK, I am having a project having many xib's and each xib contains many nswindows.

I need to use a keyboard shortcut to save for each of the window.

Do I need to create muliple mainMenu NSMenuItems for each of XIB. But another problem is there as How a single Cmd+S will know which window is in focus and how my method will get invoked.

Answer (score 2):

No You need not to make multiple NSMenuItems.

The one coming with mainMenu.xib serves this purpose.

Make an IBAction of `File->Save` menu and use it as :

```
- (IBAction)saveMenu:(id)sender {
    NSWindow *currentWindow=[NSApp keyWindow];
    NSLog(@"this is key window  : %@", currentWindow.title);
}
```

This will give you the active window.

In each of the controllers, you need to override

```
- (void)saveDocument:(id)sender;
```

And bind it using IB.